# If function result not the expected value

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

I'm very new at this and was wondering why my code is not working:

`=IF(LEFT(A16, 5)="B", "yes", "no")`

A16 is written as PD41B1 -- which should return a yes, but it only returns no.

When my code refers to (A16, 1)="P" it will work, but for any value past A16>1, the code doesn't work.

Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: You should use MID function if you want check if the 5th character in the input string is B or not.

Answer (score 1):

> When my code refers to (A16, 1)="P" it will work, but for any value past A16>1, the code doesn't work.

**You are using the function improperly.**  The function returns the numbers of characters indicated (left to right).  If the number indicated is 5, then the function will return 5 characters.

This means that your code would return **PD41B** which is indeed not equal to **B**.  This matches the behavior you have witnessed since returning 1 character, from left to right, would indeed be equal to **P**.

```
=IF(LEFT(A16, 5)="B", "yes", "no")
```

So the proper conditional for the code would be the following:

```
=IF(LEFT(A16, 5)="PD41B", "yes", "no")
```

Comment: Right

So let me clarify, I'm trying to refer to the 5th value of A16, and if it is that value (in this case, B) then it would return a yes, otherwise it would be no.

ie:
Based on the original code given: A16 = PD41B1 and should return "yes".
A17 = PD41S1 and should return "no". (assuming code is adjusted for A17)

Comment: The function doesn't work like that.  You are turning 5 characters from left to right, which means the string returned would be "PB41B" not "B".  What you want to do is possible, but your question specifically is asking, about the LEFT function.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest two possible method, helps to find the 5th character, and tests with IF.*

[image]

**Note:**

- *`LEFT(A16, 5)` , extracts 5 characters form left rather than the 5th character B.*
- Formula in cell F131:

  `=IF(MID(E133&" ",5,1)="B", "Yes", "No")`
- Formula in cell G131:

  ```
  =IF(LEFT(RIGHT(E133,LEN(E133)-5+1),1)="B","Yes","No")
  ```

*Adjust cell references and position of the character in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Write your concern that Y this has been down voted,, help me to improve!!